# Ошибка при работе с вычисление MSE keras

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

```py
data = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, 500)
e = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, 500)
# define weight
w = np.random.uniform(0, 0.9, 40)
w.shape = (20, 2)
y = data * 0.1 + 0.05 + e

# Define the model
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', input_dim=1))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001), loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model

# Use the model
z = np.zeros(20)
for number in range(20):
    model = baseline_model()
    model.set_weights([array([[w[number][0]]], dtype=float32), array([w[number][1]], dtype=float32)])
    y_predict = model.predict(data)
    z[number] = losses.mean_squared_error(y, np.ravel(y_predict))
print(z)
```

При выполнении данного кода вылетает ошибка:

> z[number] = losses.mean_squared_error(np.ravel(y), np.ravel(y_predict))
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

, где `y` и `y_predict` являются array.

Подскажите, где я ошибаюсь и как это дело исправить?

Comment: Прошу прощения, неверно ошибку скопировал

Comment: Вы пытаетесь присвоить numpy array элементу другого numpy array. Numpy в отличие от обычного Python такое не позволяет

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает изза того что вы пытаетесь присвоить элементу Numpy 1D Array другой Numpy 1D Array (вектор) вместо скалярного значения.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [54]: a = np.arange(1, 11)

In [55]: a
Out[55]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

In [56]: a[0] = np.arange(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-b0f3b62a61f5> in <module>
----> 1 a[0] = np.arange(10)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

---

**NOTE:** но главная проблема, по-моему, в неправильном использовании Keras модели. Вы пытаетесь вручную присвоить веса модели вместо того чтобы обучить её.

Обычно это делается так - допустим нам даны следующие датасеты:

- X_train - входные данные (обучающая выборка)
- Y_train - результирующие данные (обучающая выборка)
- X_test - входные данные (тестовая выборка)
- Y_test - результирующие данные (тестовая выборка)

далее строится модель (можно как у вас):

```
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', input_dim=1))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001), 
                  loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    return model
```

обучаем модель:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), epochs=100, batch_size=32)
```

оценка модели:

```
scores  = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
```

используем обученную модель для предсказаний:

```
Y_predicted = model.predict(X_unknown)
```